# Azure App Insights - How to plot over time(say 1h) so we can see how the success percentage changes over time?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

```
requests
| summarize Failure=count(resultCode contains "500" or resultCode contains "503"), Success=count(resultCode contains "200")
| extend Percentage=((Success*1.0)/(Success+Failure))*100
```

The above code would display the success rate per any hour/day given in search query. Need a query that can display success rate over time. Is that possible ?

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yYW8.png)

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [bin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction) function of kusto.

For example, say 1 hour, the sample code looks like below:

```
requests
| summarize Failure=count(resultCode contains "500" or resultCode contains "503"), Success=count(resultCode contains "200") by length=bin(timestamp,1h)
| extend Percentage=((Success*1.0)/(Success+Failure))*100
```

Here is the test result:

[image]